# regexp for replacing symbols enclosing latex displayed math

Tags: regex

Sometimes in Latex I need to replace the symbols `$$` enclosing some math syntax with
with `\[` at the beginning and `\]` at the end. Often both occurrences are on isolated lines, so I can't use anchors like `^` or `$`.

Minimal example:
I want to change

```
    $$
      x^2        
    $$
```

to

```
    \[
      x^2
    \]
```

The math syntax may run for well over two lines. I usually do it manually. Is there a regexp which would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\$\$(.*?)\$\$
```

But do mind you need to activate [`dotAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll.) mode.

If your language doesn't support regex flags, use

```
\$\$((.|\n)*?)\$\$
```

instead.

Here's an example in javascript:

```js
const regex = /\$\$(.*?)\$\$/gs;

const source = `
    $$
      x^2        
    $$
`;

const result = source.replace(regex, '\\[$1\\]');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Great. It works. I didn't know about using $1.